# laravel model does not insert 0 value into SQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, laravel-4

I am trying to store an array into the permissions column of my DB when registering a user.

In my controller I use:

```
$user->permissions = array(
                'read' => $data['read_permission'], 
                'comment' => ($data['write_permission'] >= 1 ? 1 : 0), 
                'edit' => ($data['write_permission'] >= 2 ? 1 : 0), 
                'edit_all' => '1'
                );
$user->save();
```

User Model fillable attributes:

```
protected $fillable = array('email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'company_id', 'department_id', 'phone_number', 'phone_ext', 'permissions');
```

The issue I am having is that if any of the values in the array are 0, then it will not insert that key (of the permissions array) into the DB. If a value is 1 or anything else, then it will insert to the database.

For a temporary work around, I use:

```
$permissions = array(
                'read' => $data['read_permission'], 
                'comment' => ($data['write_permission'] >= 1 ? 1 : 0), 
                'edit' => ($data['write_permission'] >= 2 ? 1 : 0), 
                'edit_all' => '1'
                );
DB::table('users')->where('id','=',$user->id)->update(['permissions' => json_encode($permissions)]);
```

Why won't the model save the keys when their values are 0?

Example for clarification:

```
$user->permissions = array(
                'read' =>1, 
                'comment' => 1, 
                'edit' => 0, 
                'edit_all' => 0
                );
$user->save();
```

saves {"read":1,"comment":1} in the DB

```
$user->permissions = array(
                'read' =>0, 
                'comment' => 0, 
                'edit' => 0, 
                'edit_all' => 0
                );
$user->save();
```

saves blank (but not null) in the DB.

Comment: Try putting quotes around the numbers.

Comment: '0' still eliminates the key.